# siteMesh + Spring 3.0 + Exclude pattern

Tags: spring-mvc, sitemesh

I would like to have all the requests decorated except my welcome page. This is the default page I display when only my application context is in the url with no other path elements.

> http://hostname:8080/MyApp/ -> This should not be decorated. This should show my Welcome page. How do I exclude this?
>
> http://hostname:8080/MyApp/user -> This gets decorated now with below config

I have the following decorators.xml.

```
<!-- Any urls that are excluded will never be decorated by Sitemesh -->
<excludes>
    <pattern>/exclude/*</pattern>
</excludes>

<decorator name="main" page="main.jsp">
    <pattern>/*</pattern>
</decorator>
```

I am using Spring MVC where the dispatch servlet is configured to take all the input requests. and I have a controller to display my Welcome page for request mapping "/".

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I found a way to do it myself. In my welcome.jsp I added a meta tag as shown below and in the decorators.xml you add a decorator for welcome.


    <head>
        <meta name="decorator" content="welcome">    
    </head>

decorators.xml

    <decorator name="main" page="main.jsp">
        <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>

    <decorator name="welcome" page="welcome.jsp"/>

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it myself. In my welcome.jsp I added a meta tag as shown below and in the decorators.xml you add a decorator for welcome.

```
<head> 
     <meta name="decorator" content="welcome"> 
</head>
```

decorators.xml

```
<decorator name="main" page="main.jsp"> 
     <pattern>/*</pattern> 
</decorator> 

<decorator name="welcome" page="welcome.jsp"/>
```