# Exclude sitemesh

Tags: sitemesh

i would like to exclude sitemesh decorator for some of my files in a project. but how to do it. my file names is listApps.jsp

this is my decorators.xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/pages">
<excludes>
    <pattern>/j_spring_security_logout</pattern>
    <pattern>/pages/logout-redirect.jsp</pattern>
    <pattern>/flexweb/*</pattern>
    <pattern>/ApplicationScaffold.html</pattern>
    <pattern>/listApps.html</pattern>
</excludes>

<decorator name="main" page="main.jsp">
    <pattern>/*</pattern>
</decorator>
```

any help? thanks

Comment: i tried to do the one that have been discussed here :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153167/sitemesh-spring-3-0-exclude-pattern, but it still didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

well, you could create another template named nothingfancy and you don't do anything special for that one

put it first so it's evaluated before

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<decorators defaultdir="/app/decorators">

    <decorator name="nothingfancy" page="nothingfancy.jsp">
        <pattern>/j_spring_security_logout</pattern>
        <pattern>/pages/logout-redirect.jsp</pattern>
        <pattern>/flexweb/*</pattern>
        <pattern>/ApplicationScaffold.html</pattern>
        <pattern>/listApps.html</pattern>
    </decorator>

    <decorator name="main" page="main.jsp">
        <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>
```